# Find a row in a dataframe based on a column value from another dataframe and apply filter to it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type_id' : [1,2,3,4,3], 'count' : [12,11,15,16,2], 'unique_id' : ['1|12','2|11','3|15','4|16','3|2']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'type_id' : [1,3,76,12,11,1], 'count' : [8,6,15,16,5,17], 'col3' : [1,5,7,3,4,7], 'unique_id' : ['1|8','3|6','76|12','12|16','11|5','1|17']})
```

df1

```
    type_id     count   unique_id
0   1   12  1|12
1   2   11  2|11
2   3   15  3|15
3   4   16  4|16
4   3   2   3|2
```

df2

```
type_id     count   col3    unique_id
0   1   8   1   1|8
1   3   6   5   3|6
2   76  15  7   76|12
3   12  16  3   12|16
4   11  5   4   11|5
5   1   17  7   1|17
```

Here, unique_id is a combination of type_id and count.

Now, I want to retrieve rows from df2 where `df2['type_id'] == df1['id'] & df2['count']<df1['count']`

i.e., I want rows where the two ids match and the corresponding count in df2 is less than the count of df1

Expected output:

```
    type_id     count   col3    unique_id
0   1   8   1   1|8
1   3   6   5   3|6
```

when I try doing this directly I'm getting an error :

`Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects`

How do I perform this operation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for match by `id` columns to get `Series` with same length like `df2`, so possible compare by `df2['count']` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df2[df2['count'] < df2['type_id'].map(df1.set_index('type_id')['count'])]
print (df)
   type_id  count  col3 unique_id
0        1      8     1       1|8
1        3      6     5       3|6
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df2['type_id'].map(df1.set_index('type_id')['count']))
0    12.0
1    15.0
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    12.0
Name: type_id, dtype: float64
```

EDIT: Because duplicates in `df1['type_id']` is possible create unique `unique_id` by chain counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'type_id' : [1,1,1,4], 'count' : [12,11,15,16]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'type_id' : [1,3,76,12,11,1], 
                    'count' : [8,6,15,16,5,17], 'col3' : [1,5,7,3,4,7]})



df1['unique_id1'] = (df1['type_id'].astype(str) + '|' + 
                     df1.groupby('type_id').cumcount().astype(str))
df2['unique_id1'] = (df2['type_id'].astype(str) + '|' + 
                     df2.groupby('type_id').cumcount().astype(str))
print (df1)
   type_id  count unique_id1
0        1     12       1|0
1        1     11       1|1
2        1     15       1|2
3        4     16       4|0

print (df2)
   type_id  count  col3 unique_id1
0        1      8     1       1|0
1        3      6     5       3|0
2       76     15     7      76|0
3       12     16     3      12|0
4       11      5     4      11|0
5        1     17     7       1|1

df = df2[df2['count'] < df2['unique_id1'].map(df1.set_index('unique_id1')['count'])]
print (df)
   type_id  count  col3 unique_id
0        1      8     1       1|0
```

Comment: @jesrael - The duplicates are necessary because it has many other columns which is required for later logic. I'm sorry for the confusion. I will change the example again.

Comment: @jesrael - Expected output : type_id : [1], count : [8] (rows from df2)

Comment: @jesrael - the unique_id is a combination of type_id | count. The 5th row in df2 is omitted because it's count 17>15 ( highest count for id-1)

Comment: @sunehaks - Ok, be free change it to `unique_id1`, answer was edited.

Comment: @sunehaks - Yes, `the unique_id is a combination of type_id | count.` - But I cannot use this fact, because cannot match `df1.unique_id` and `df2.unique_id` because different values. So my solution create `unique_id1` by counter for possible matching. But maybe ony not understand it, because missing [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (here duplicated `type_id`)